# Как опубликовать свою библиотеку gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

P.S: в maven и gradle я полный ноль.

Я пишу, скажем так, библиотеку и хочу попробовать залить её в общий доступ. Как я понимаю многие для этого используют сайт, назначение которого мне не известно, - `sonatype.org`, и подключают к нему свою СКВ. Я же хочу понять как можно обойтись без него, как можно допустим просто `.jar` файл использовать (локально) или подключить свой домен.

И делать к примеру так:

```
repositories {
    maven { url = 'мойдомент.пуп' }
}
dependencies {
    compileOnly: 'org.group:artifact:1.0-Alpha'
}
```